# Custom class deallocated as soon as the app starts

Tags: objective-c, dealloc

I've added a class object to the nib file. All connections are made.

But for some reason, the object is deallocated as soon as it's created.

Here's the code:

control.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface control : NSObject 
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *PlayerScore;
}
-(IBAction) addPoint: sender;
-(void) dealloc;
@end
```

control.m:

```
#import "control.h"
@implementation control
-(IBAction)addPoint: sender {
    NSLog(@"Ohhai. Didn't crash."); //Doesn't even make it to this stage.
    int i = [PlayerScore.text intValue];
    PlayerScore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",++i];
}
-(void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ZOMGWTF?");
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Here is the console log:

> [Session started at 2010-06-09 19:47:57 +1000.]
>   2010-06-09 19:47:58.771 App[91100:207] ZOMGWTF?

And after I click the button which messages addPoint, of course, it crashes.

> 2010-06-09 19:47:59.703 App[91100:207] *** -[control] performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3843d80

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing control.h to be:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface control : NSObject 
{
    UILabel *PlayerScore;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *PlayerScore;
-(IBAction) addPoint: sender;
-(void) dealloc;
@end
```

And then add a @synthesize to the implementation section of 'control'.

Also, who has reference to the control class in the NIB?

Comment: Tried that but it still gets deallocated at runtime.

control has no reference outlets connected.

Comment: Connect the reference to the File Owner... I assume you are building with the Garbage Collector. With no reference to hold the 'control' object to the GC is sweeping it away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove from your Interface Builder the ViewController and use File Owner's as "control".

First of this, change `@interface control : NSObject` to `@interface control : UIViewController`

change anything?

Ah, why you use

```
-(IBAction) addPoint: sender;
```

instead

```
-(IBAction) addPoint:(id) sender;
```

?